# How to add a macro definition to FX Composer

Tags: shader, nvidia, fxcomposer

I've tried to add a macro definition to FX Composer in my project settings using the Project > HLSL/CG > Compiler Options fields. In the two HLSL fields I have /DMYPROJECT and for Cg -DMYPROJECT.

When compiling Cg shaders, this works as expected, but I cannot get it to work for HLSL. Using the same option in command line on fxc.exe works.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to test;

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT
#error ABC
#endif
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FX Composer appears to execute #error directives regardless of other preprocessor directives, at least for HLSL.  If you try your test with some actual code, like setting the pixel color to black or something, I think you'll find that it works.  It worked for me, anyway.  Your question actually helped me figure out how to do this, although I ended up going to Assets, Effects, myeffect, myshader.fx, Properties, Compiler Options.

Also important: in the Compiler Options field, I entered the macro like MYPROJECT, not /DMYPROJECT and that worked.  I'm using FX Composer 2.53.0524.1905 with a D3D9 HLSL shader.

Comment: Yup, that appears to be the case. Cheers!